# Is $\forall y \, \forall z \, y \cdot z = x \rightarrow y = 1 \lor z = 1$ the correct way to describe a prime number?

Tags: prime-numbers

The definition is taken from [here](https://youtu.be/eUywVvl_1oE?t=219). Is

$$\forall y \; \forall z \; y \cdot z = x \rightarrow y = 1 \lor z = 1$$

the correct way to define a prime number? Do you have a link to an article where prime numbers are defined this way?

If you would have to write this as a definition in a book or in an article, how would you write it?

Comment: That would make $1$ a prime number, which it isn't.

Comment: Do you want members of $\Bbb N$ only?

Comment: "If you would have to write this as a definition in a book or in an article, how would you write it?" You wouldn't. Why don't you just use common language and say "prime numbers"? Is there a specific purpose behind trying to define prime numbers in formal notation? I have clicked the video but I don't understand German.

Comment: I agree with the comment of @AdamRubinson.  On the one hand, yes the posted definition can be remedied to be a valid definition of primes: you simply insist that $y,z \in \Bbb{Z^+}$, and that the *candidate prime* $x \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.$ However, the more natural and more common definition is that $p$ is prime if and only if $p$ is a positive integer $\geq 2$ such that the only positive integer divisors of $p$ are $1$ and $p$ itself.